# How to bring the results of an array from for()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you look at this code, then we will get three 3 `alerts()`

```js
var names = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Josh'];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var memberx = names[i];
    alert(memberx); 
}
```

But if I bring out the `alert()` from `for()`. I only get 1 `alert()` and only **josh**. Like this

```js
var names = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Josh'];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var memberx = names[i];
}
alert(memberx);
```

Can I make 3 times `alerts()` if the code are outside `for()`? Like first example

Comment: If you want 3 alerts, it should be inside the `for` loop (or inside a separate `for` loop).

Comment: Well, you can not `alert` three times without, either calling `alert` three times, or putting `alert` in a loop executed 3 times.

Comment: I guess you could concatenate to a string in the loop and alert once... i.e "Peter, Tom, Josh". Something like `output += names[i];`.

Comment: You're getting a lot of downvotes because your requirements are very unclear. Please explain *why* you want to move the `alert` outside the `for`, and *why* you need 3 alerts. These requirements seem to be contradictory, and they need further explanation. Edit your question to clarify, and many of those downvotes may be reversed.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts by editing garbage into it.

Comment: If you want your own post deleted and can not delete it using the delete link below the question, then you can select flag➞"in need of moderator intervention" and state your request that the post be deleted. The moderator who handles the flag may, or may not, delete the post at their discretion, largely based on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting `memberx` over and over again. If you don't want the `alert` in a for loop you can use `forEach` instead and do:

```
names.forEach(alert)
```